# No audio after pausing and resuming Netflix, Hulu and Media Center Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, media-center

I just built myself a home theater to use with netflix, hulu, and windows media center.  Whenever I pause netflix, hulu or a recorded show in MC and then resume play, there is no sound.  If I resume immediately, the sound works but if I wait a minute or more, the sound is gone.

The work around for me is to go to sound in the control panel, click on the play back device the is NOT my default device and set it as default.

Then click on the original default device and reset it as the default and then the sound will work again until the next time I pause and resume.  Then I have to go thru that whole process again.  It is quite maddening and I need a fix for it.

I am using Windows 7 and I am computer literate so if I have to edit the registry, I am OK with that.  Is there maybe a time setting that will allow sound to come back if paused for longer periods of time?  I don't know but would sure appreciate any help with this.